# ¿Consulta SQL que me traiga todos los registros del día domingo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta SQL que me devuelva todos los registros de una tabla del día domingo.

```
SELECT * 
        FROM "TABLA" 
        WHERE (aquí debería estar la condición que sea domingo)
```

Comment: Que motor de base de datos? las soluciones pueden que no sean las mismas

Comment: Estoy usando SQL SERVER

Answer (score 4):

En SQL Server puedes usar [`DATEPART()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms174420(v=sql.120).aspx):

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

SELECT  *
         FROM Tabla
         WHERE DATEPART(DW,CampoFecha) = 7;
```

Es importante en primer lugar correr el `SET DATEFIRST 1;` con esto nos aseguramos que vamos a considerar que la semana comienza el lunes y el día de la semana 7 (`DW`) será el domingo.

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente aportar que también puedes determinar el día Domingo usando **[`DATENAME`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/datename-transact-sql)** del siguiente modo:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLA 
WHERE DATENAME(DW, colFecha)='Sunday';
```

Lo único es que el nombre del día tiene que ser escrito en el idioma que tenga configurado el manejador de base de datos (no el sistema operativo).

De hecho, si configuras el idioma antes, te arrojará los datos en el idioma que hayas seteado. Por ejemplo, si el manejador está en su idioma por defecto (Inglés)  y quieres escribir la consulta para español.

1. Estableces el idioma a español.

   ```
   SET LANGUAGE Spanish;
   ```
2. Escribes la consulta con el día de la semana en español:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM TABLA 
   WHERE DATENAME(DW, colFecha)='Domingo';
   ```

### Código de prueba

Veamos una prueba de concepto cambiando a algunos idiomas.

<kbd>**[VER DEMO EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/BFEAL84921)**</kbd>

```
CREATE TABLE  prueba_datename
 ( 
    id          INT              NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
    fecha       DATETIME         NOT NULL 
 );


INSERT INTO prueba_datename (fecha) VALUES 
('2018-02-18'),
('2018-02-19'),
('2018-02-20'),
('2018-02-21'),
('2018-02-22'),
('2018-02-23'),
('2018-02-24');


    SELECT 
        DATENAME(DW, fecha) day
    FROM prueba_datename ;

    SELECT 
        id, 
        fecha fecha_uk 
    FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Sunday';


SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

    SELECT 
        DATENAME(DW, fecha) dia
    FROM prueba_datename ;

    SELECT 
        id,  
        fecha fecha_es
    FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Domingo';


SET LANGUAGE French;

   SELECT 
       DATENAME(DW, fecha) jour
   FROM prueba_datename ;

   SELECT 
       id, 
       fecha fecha_fr 
   FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Dimanche';


SET LANGUAGE Italian;

    SELECT 
        DATENAME(DW, fecha) giorno
    FROM prueba_datename ;

    SELECT 
        id, 
        fecha fecha_it 
    FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Domenica';
```

---

### Resultados:

#### Inglés

```
    SELECT 
        DATENAME(DW, fecha) day
    FROM prueba_datename ;

day
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday

    SELECT 
        id, 
        fecha fecha_uk 
    FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Sunday';

id  fecha_uk
1   18.02.2018 00:00:00
```

#### Español

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish;

    SELECT 
        DATENAME(DW, fecha) dia
    FROM prueba_datename ;

dia
Domingo
Lunes
Martes
Miércoles
Jueves
Viernes
Sábado

    SELECT 
        id,  
        fecha fecha_es
    FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Domingo';

id  fecha_es
1   18.02.2018 00:00:00
```

#### Francés

```
SET LANGUAGE French;

   SELECT 
       DATENAME(DW, fecha) jour
   FROM prueba_datename ;

jour
dimanche
lundi
mardi
mercredi
jeudi
vendredi
samedi


   SELECT 
       id, 
       fecha fecha_fr 
   FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Dimanche';

id  fecha_fr
1   18.02.2018 00:00:00
```

#### Italiano

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian;


    SELECT 
        DATENAME(DW, fecha) giorno
    FROM prueba_datename ;

giorno
domenica
lunedì
martedì
mercoledì
giovedì
venerdì
sabato

    SELECT 
        id, 
        fecha fecha_it 
    FROM prueba_datename WHERE DATENAME(DW, fecha)='Domenica'; 

id  fecha_it
1   18.02.2018 00:00:00
```

Comment: Solo se podría considerar si el lenguaje en uso es el inglés (`us_english`). Para revisar ello solo sería necesario realizar [`SELECT @@LANGUAGE`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/language-transact-sql).

Comment: @Davlio funciona con cualquier idioma, sólo habría que cambiar la forma en que se escribe el nombre del día que se quiera filtrar, por supuesto. He editado la respuesta incluyendo una prueba con diferentes idiomas.